Using update contact to monitor customer engagement with multiple Journeys
I have 2 separate journeys running off 2 different data extensions. A select group of customers enter into Journey 1 first and then 2 weeks later all customers enter into Journey 2. I want to track whether customers who receive Journey 1 as a primer are more likely to engage with Journey 2.
I was planning on adding an engagement split in Journey 2 to check if customers have clicked and then using Update contact to populate a field in the Journey 1 data extension if they have. Then I can set my goal for Journey 1 as 'Click on Journey 2' and monitor how successful it is.

Will this work to keep track of those who engage with Journey 2?
Do the data extensions in both journeys need to be set up as contact data so they can be linked and updated?
I will hold customers in Journey 1 for 3 weeks before exiting to allow time to see whether they engage with Journey 2 and update the goal. Will this work?

